# filter array with another all array elements - Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i have a string array like this:

```
firstArray = {"1", "2", "3", "4" };
```

and i have second array like this:

```
secondArray = {"2", "5", "6", "7" };
```

if i want to stream with one element, i can do like this:

```
firstArray.stream()
    .filter(element -> !element.equals("2"))
    .forEach((element) -> {
        finalArrayList.add(element);
    }
);
```

how can i stream first array with second arrays all elements in java 8 ?

Comment: Use static `Stream.concat(Stream, Stream)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to achieve? What is the expected result here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep only elements of the first array that you don't have in the second array using the `Stream API`, you could do it like this:

```
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(firstArray)
    .filter(el -> Arrays.stream(secondArray).noneMatch(el::equals))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to do? Get all the elements in the first array that are also present in the second array?

Like this:

```
String[] firstArray = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
String[] secondArray = {"2", "5", "6", "7"};

List<String> finalArrayList = Arrays.stream(firstArray)
        .filter(element -> arrayContains(secondArray, element))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using the following utility method:

```
public static <T> boolean arrayContains(T[] array, T element) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                 .filter(e -> e.equals(element))
                 .findFirst().isPresent();
}
```

Note: Instead of using `forEach` and adding the results to `finalArrayList`, use a collector. That's more pure, from a functional programming point of view.

*edit* - With Holger's tips (see his comment below):

```
public static <T> boolean arrayContains(T[] array, T element) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                 .anyMatch(e -> e.equals(element));
}
```

Comment: Mind the existence of `anyMatch(predicate)` which is to prefer over `filter(predicate).findFirst().isPresent()`. Besides, if you are only interested in the presence of a match, `findAny()` would be more appropriate than `findFirst()`…